# Redirecting HTTP-Request to HTTPS through httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, http, https

I currently try to redirect the HTTP-request to HTTPS, but couldnt find a solution for this,

in my httpd.conf I have the following redirection to my Tomcat application:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ /sweetApp/
```

I found out that I can use

> Redirect
>   **or**
>   RedirectMatch
>   **or** (RewriteCond and RewriteRule) - Combinations

in the HTTPD.conf.

Another way seems to be the HTACCESS-File, but I'm working on Windows and dont know how / dont want to use a HTACCESS-File.

How can I perform this redirection?

(I have no Virtual Hosts, using a plain single site installation)

Answer (score 0):

So according to your description you have two hosts defined, one is for HTTP and one is for HTTPS, right?

So in the one for HTTP you can add a line like this one:

```
RedirectMatch .* https://yourdomain
```

This will match the requested URI against the pattern `.*`, so it will always match. Then it redirects to the absolute URL `https://yourdomain`